# Most minimalist equipment setup to DIY tires

Tags: tires

What would be the most minimalist equipment lineup necessary for a DIY-er to be able to do tires? I know tire shops have a rim installation wheel or whatever that is called -- is there a compact tool that would do the same for a backyard mechanic?

Comment: There is a reason they are called "tire irons". You can use them to manually put tires on the rim.

Comment: @Paulster2 -- you mean the + looking things ?

Comment: https://www.rosevillemoparts.com/product/jack-handle-tire-iron-short/ ... probably what you might be aware of, however the following are more so actual tire irons: https://tiresupplynetwork.com/products/ken-tool-t45ac-37-classic-tubeless-tire-iron?variant=7312672260143 ... & ... https://www.cyclegear.com/accessories/motion-pro-spoon-type-tire-iron

Answer (score 1):

Three things come to mind:

1. Tire irons.  You will probably need 3 but I've seen some do it with 2.
2. Some sort of bead breaking mechanism.  There are commercially made ones as well as many variations of improvised methods.  A quick search will yield many choices.
3. Air source to seat the bead after the new tire is mounted.

Comment: What about balancing?

Comment: He said minimalist.

Comment: Well, if you are truly saying a "minimalist" you don't need a separate "bead breaking mechanism" if you have a car at your disposal. If you run over a flat tire with a car, you can easily break the bead. Just have to roll it over the tire and not the rim. Comes right loose.

Comment: Note that I said, "some sort of bead breaking mechanism"  A car might fit that definition as might a sledge hammer a "C" clamp, etc.  You could also probably forget the tire irons and use a couple of screwdrivers.

Comment: If you wanted your answers to "stand out", you should attempt to add such details.